# AngularJs: init directive model with parameter from Url

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have several instances of specific directive like that:

```
<type="text" my-directive ng-model="formData.property1">
<type="text" my-directive ng-model="formData.property2">
```

formData.propery is an object like `{ name: '', code: '' }`. `formData.propery.name` is used in view layer and `formData.propery.code` is sent to the server as value.

I want to init these directives from URL parameters - pass codes and get whole object as model value.

The difficulties here are:

1. I can't call function in directive scope that gets object from server with specific code, because it violates separation of concerns of parent scope and directive scope.
2. I can't init models from parent scope because of asyncronous call type of $http request.
3. I can't use specific init function in directive that gets object from server by model variable name because it a bit awkward and mess the code.

So what is proper way to do that?

Example 1:

```
    getObj1 = (code)->
        $http({
            url: '/api/service/GetByCode'
            method: 'POST'
            data: { code: code }
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
        })
        .success((data)->
            $scope.formData.property1 = angular.fromJson(data.result)
        )

    getObj2 = (code)->
        $http({
            url: '/api/service/GetByCode'
            method: 'POST'
            data: { code: code }
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
        })
        .success((data)->
            $scope.formData.property2 = angular.fromJson(data.result)
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've just needed to pass property to assign as argument to function using closure:

```
   getObj = (code, prop)->
        theProp = prop
        $http({
            url: '/api/service/GetByCode'
            method: 'POST'
            data: { code: code }
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
        })
        .success((data)->
            theProp = angular.fromJson(data.result)
        )
```

and then call it like this:

```
getObj(someCode1, scope.formData.property1)
getObj(someCode2, scope.formData.property2)
```